# "What is a slam attack?" question - should it be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What is a slam attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47920/) - the question is about "Slam" attack name, particularly the Doppelganger's attack:

> **Slam.** Melee Weapon Attack: +6 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 7 (1d6 + 4) bludgeoning damage.

The OP asks: "What, descriptively, does an attack of this kind entail?"

I see several problems with this question:

1. The question implies all "slam" attack are the same, however, a Doppelganger's *slam* might differ from, say, a Water Elemental *slam*. It's just an attack title, like "Bite" or "Claw". Besides the generic word meaning, it is impossible to find exact but universal "slam" attack description, thus, answer the question.
2. The question is about a particular attack title from the MM. I can't understand why only the "slam" was chosen. Why shouldn't we ask "What is a Bite attack?" then, "What is a Claw attack?", "What is a Shortsword attack?", etc.
3. In 5e MM many attacks aren't actually described, all the descriptive details are up to the DM and, in the end of the day, are opinion-based.

However there were no "primarily opinion-based" VTCs so far and the question has a decent positive score. Why shouldn't it be closed?

Comment: Wait, I have one of these!? :O

Answer (score 11):

### Because it is answerable

1. Bite implies that you attack a target with your teeth, claw with your claws. It is very likely that slam similarly implies certain unifying characteristics. The accepted answer on the question addresses this. *You* might not have known what the unifying characteristics were, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.
2. Because the method of delivery for those attacks is obvious - they lend themselves to visual description by default.
3. No, but most lend themselves to visual description - an eye ray is exactly that. Slam is abnormal in that it does not.

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer quotes 3.5e MM.

Comment: @enkryptor Acceptable by the terms of the question